# Use a file from GCP Secret Manager as Spring PropertySource

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud-gcp

We use GCP Secret Manager and load a whole property file into a secret.

Is it possible to use this file (in fact it's a string) as a PropertySource in Spring Boot so that we can access the single properties with `@Value`?

Comment: If you use Cloud Run I wrote an article/hack on that: https://medium.com/google-cloud/mount-a-file-as-a-volume-in-cloud-run-facc74c02cc6

Comment: We are using Kubernetes

Comment: Have you consider using CSI driver and combine that load mode with my article proposal?: https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/using-other-products#google-kubernetes-engine